# Using a third party lib in an annotation processor with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

maybe I do not see the wood for the trees, but I made an AnnotationProcessor and embedded it in eclipse. Works fine so far....but what if I need some 3rd party libs? I don't see any option to add those jars to the classpath. How/Where do I configure that in eclipse?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution thanks to the eclipse forum :). Third party libraries have to be added to the factory path ... just like the jar, which includes the processor.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project. Select "Build Path"/"Configure Build Path". When dialog appears choose "Libraries" tab. Here you can add almost anything you want to the class path.

Comment: Unfortunatly, that does not work ;). As far as I see it, the classpath/buildpath I configure for the project (which uses the proccessor) is not passed to the processor. I added the 3rd party lib I am using but still I receive a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError... :(